# how to use augmented reality to change the color of a qr code once it is detected using with arcore and ml kit firebase

Tags: android, arcore, firebase-mlkit

I need to develop an android application that allows me to scan a barcode and if that barcode is saved in a predefined list change the color of the barcode to green and if not to red using arcore and ml kit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution that can be developed in no time is to add a green/red rectangle around the QR code. Otherwise you would have to update the screen pixels where you have the black (or white as you wish) and replace them with green/red pixels. From the developement point of view the second solution is far more complex than the other one, considering the techology that you are using.